# 2D array in android without specify dimention length

Tags: java, android

```html
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final String[][] Array2D = new String[2][10];


        Button enter =(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        final EditText valueEditText=(Button)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        final EditText xEditText=(Button)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        final EditText yEditText=(Button)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);


enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String value =valueEditText.getText().toString();
        int x=Integer.valueOf(xEditText.getText().toString());
        int y=Integer.valueOf(yEditText.getText().toString());
        Array2D[x][y]=value;
        
    }
});



    }


}
```

I am working on a project with 2D String array. At every click, I enter new addresses and values to be entered in that address.

The problem is: I want to do that with dynamic array (without defining specific dimensions for long and width)

Could any one can help me please ???

Answer (score 2):

The length of an array is fixed.

You should use a `List<List<String>>` instead.

Comment: I try to use it but i can Knaw haw to add the new value at the entered adress..

could you help me how to do that with "list"??

Comment: There's too much to explain in comments. Have a look at the documentation for `ArrayList`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html I'd advise trying to get used to a 1D list first.

Comment: thanks for your help .i see the link but still cant enter the value at x,y adress. thanks again.